# Problem loading the right path in a dynamic page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm making a dynamic page loading video from a database and I want to watch them clicking on the button view, the problem is that the actual code always starts the same video regardless of which video I try to watch, how can I resolve it? I know the code isn't the best so I will accept every piece of advice, thanks. and here is my code:

```
     <?php
      require '../Tools/Database_connection.php';

      $query = 'SELECT * FROM video';
      if($result = $conn->query($query)){
        $num = $conn->affected_rows;
        if($num > 0) { 
          while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?> 
            <div class='col'>
              <div class='card shadow-sm'>
                <title><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></title>
                <img class='Thumbnail' src='<?php echo $row['Thumbnail']; ?>' alt='the Thumbnail didn t load'>
                <div class='card-body'>
                  <p><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></p>
                  <p class='card-text'><?php echo $row['Description']; ?></p>
                  <div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                      <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary' onclick='watch(<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>)'>View</button>
                        <p>
                          <?php echo $row['video_id']."<br>". 
                                    $row['Location'];?>
                        </p>
                        <div class="player_video" style="visibility: hidden;">
                        <video controls id="<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>">
                          <source src='<?php echo $row['Location']; ?>'>
                        </video>
                        </div>
                      <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class='text-muted'>9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
         <?php }
        }
      $result->close();
      }

      ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
         function watch(){
          document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>").play();
          confirm(<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>);
         }
        </script>
```

Comment: Please share more details. How do you distinguish which video should be started? Also, is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
<video controls id="myVideo">
```

You must give every video a unique id, All videos in your page has the same id, So the code always play the same video.

You should make many changes to solve this first:

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary' onclick='watch(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)'>View</button>
```

second:

```
<video controls id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

Third:
change javascript code to this:

```
 function watch(videoId){
  document.getElementById(videoId).style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById(videoId).play();
 }
```

Comment: So just to be sure i have to literally write "videoId" in the javascript code?

Comment: Name it as you like, This is a function parameter,
The important thing that you should note that I put <?php echo $row['id']; ?> as I mentioned, Where row['id'] is the unique id that you get from underline database table.

Note that I put this: <?php echo $row['id']; ?> in two places in php code here:
<button...... onclick='watch(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.....
and here:
<video controls id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

Comment: ok, i have made all the cahnges but now instead of the first video of the list it's always start the last, any advice?

Comment: Please open page source in any browser to see html contents.
check the lines like these:
<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary' onclick='watch(1)'>View</button>
and
<video controls id="1">

You should see pair of this line for every video.

Note that "1" here is id of the row, you can see another numbers, but you must see pair of these lines for every video.

Comment: Also note  $row['id'] mean the value of unique id field in videos table.
If you name this field another name - for example VID or other thing- you must replace $row['id'] with $row['VID'] or the name of unique field in your video table.

Comment: of course i changed $row['id'] with $row['video_id'](name of the field in my case) and now i controlled the id of <video> change and is different for everyone but when the function watch() is called the id called is always the last one of the list, now i will edit the answer so you can see the code modified

Comment: Please change javascript code exactly as I write in my answer:
     function watch(videoId){
      document.getElementById(videoId).style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById(videoId).play();
     }

I see that you write the code:
         function watch(){
          document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>").style.visibility = "visible";
          document.getElementById("<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>").play();
          confirm(<?php echo $row['video_id']; ?>);
         }
This is not correct and it is the reason why you always see the same video

Answer (score 1):

Your video tag is identified by an ID. So if you call the ID, only the first created  tag will be set as visible then played. Try using a class instead. You should look about the `var closestElement = targetElement.closest(selectors);`

I didn't try but your code should look like :

```
<?php
  require '../Tools/Database_connection.php';

  $query = 'SELECT * FROM video';
  if($result = $conn->query($query)){
    $num = $conn->affected_rows;
    if($num > 0) { 
      while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?> 
        <div class='col'>
          <div class='card shadow-sm'>
            <title><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></title>
            <img class='Thumbnail' src='<?php echo $row['Thumbnail']; ?>' alt='the Thumbnail didn t load'>
            <div class='card-body'>
              <p><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></p>
              <p class='card-text'><?php echo $row['Description']; ?></p>
              <div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
                <div class='btn-group'>
                  <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary' onclick='watch(e)'>View</button>
                    <div class="player_video" style="visibility: hidden;">
                    <video controls class="myVideos">
                      <source src='<?php echo $row['Location']; ?>'>
                    </video>
                    </div>
                  <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class='text-muted'>9 mins</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     <?php }
    }
  $result->close();
  }

  ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     function watch(e){
     e = e || window.event;
     var src = e.target || e.srcElement;
     var video = src.closest("video");
      video.style.visibility = "visible";
      video.play();
     }

    </script>
```